# Issue in Generation of Sequence Code using Cursor in SQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2017, seq

Code seems Correct,But giving wrong Output,Please correct me if i am doing something wrong

This is table "LoadData"

| Sequencement_CD | ID | Current_Year | Record_DT | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18AA | 109754BY6 | 2018 | 2018-01-01 | U |
| 19AA | 222367DY7 | 2019 | 2019-02-22 | A |
| 19AB | 222367DY7 | 2019 | 2020-05-26 | A |
| NULL | 222367DY7 | 2019 | 2020-06-06 | A |
| NULL | 222367DY7 | 2021 | 2020-06-06 | A |
| NULL | 29276KAR2 | 2021 | 2020-06-01 | A |
| NULL | 29276KAR2 | 2021 | 2020-07-06 | A |

I need to Generate 'Sequence_Code' for only those ID whose Status is 'A'

Alphabetic 'Sequence_Code' is combination of Last Two Digit of 'Current_Year' and 2 character alphabet like AA,AB,AC....AZ,

BA,BB,BC...BZ.  CA,CB,CC....

Below Function gives me next sequence code:

```sql
 Create FUNCTION [dbo].[GetNextSequenceCode_TEST] (@LastSeqAlphabet varchar(100))
  RETURNS varchar(100)
   AS
    BEGIN 
         DECLARE @fPart varchar(100), @lChar CHAR(1);  
                  IF(@LastSeqAlphabet IS NULL OR @LastSeqAlphabet = '')   
                   RETURN 'AA';      

                     SELECT @fPart = LEFT(@LastSeqAlphabet, LEN(@LastSeqAlphabet) - 1);  
                     SELECT @lChar = RIGHT(@LastSeqAlphabet, 1);   
                       
                  IF(@lChar = 'Z')  
                  RETURN (SELECT [dbo].[GetNextSequenceCode_TEST](@fPart)) + 'A';  
                   
              RETURN @fPart + CHAR(ASCII(@lChar)+1);  
       END
```

Table is having Duplicate ID,Each row has Different data(like 'Record_DT').

Sequence_CD must be generated based on ID and Current Year.

Rules:

1. If already ID is having Sequence_CD,then for next record which is having same ID and Tax_year,
   The code should take Biggest value of Sequence_CD (Existing for same ID and CurrentYear), and it should increment it by 1 for the next row.and update it in the table.
2. If ID is not having Sequence_CD,Then it should generate it from 'AA' i.e CurrentYear(considering last 2 digit only)+'AA'
3. IF the ID is present for another Current_Year,here also Sequence_CD should be like CurrentYear(considering last 2 digit only)+'AA'

For Every Record,i need to follow the above rule
I am doing this by using Cursor

```
    DECLARE @ID Varchar(9);
    DECLARE @Current_Year Varchar(4);
    DECLARE @Record_DT date;
    DECLARE @Seq_CD VARCHAR(4); 
    DECLARE @GeneratedSeq_CD varchar(20);   
    DECLARE @InsertedRecordsCursor as CURSOR;
    --DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(500);
    
    BEGIN
        SET @InsertedRecordsCursor = CURSOR FOR
            select ID,Current_Year,Record_DT from TestTable              
            where  Sequencement_CD IS NULL AND  Status ='A' 

                OPEN @InsertedRecordsCursor; 
                                    
                    FETCH NEXT FROM @InsertedRecordsCursor INTO @ID,@Current_Year,@Record_DT
                    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                        BEGIN
                        
                        Select top 1 @Seq_CD = Substring(Sequencement_CD,3,2) from TestTable 
                        where Current_Year = @Current_Year And ID = @ID
                        AND Sequencement_CD IS NOT NULL  
                        ORDER BY Sequencement_CD desc

                        IF(@Seq_CD IS NULL OR @Seq_CD = '')   
                        Set @Seq_CD = ''; 
                                    
                            UPDATE TestTable   
                            SET Sequencement_CD = (RIGHT(@Current_Year,2)) + dbo.GetNextSequenceCode_TEST (RTRIM(@Seq_CD))       
                            WHERE ID = @ID And Current_Year = @Current_Year 
                            And Record_DT = @Record_DT  
                                                            
                        FETCH NEXT FROM @InsertedRecordsCursor INTO @ID,@Current_Year,@Record_DT

                        END; 
                    
                CLOSE @InsertedRecordsCursor ;
                DEALLOCATE @InsertedRecordsCursor;
    END;
```

Expected Output:

| Sequencement_CD | ID | Current_Year | Record_DT | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18AA | 109754BY6 | 2018 | 2018-01-01 | U |
| 19AA | 222367DY7 | 2019 | 2019-02-22 | A |
| 19AB | 222367DY7 | 2019 | 2020-05-26 | A |
| 19AC | 222367DY7 | 2019 | 2020-06-06 | A |
| 21AA | 222367DY7 | 2021 | 2020-06-06 | A |
| 21AA | 29276KAR2 | 2021 | 2020-06-01 | A |
| 21AB | 29276KAR2 | 2021 | 2020-07-06 | A |

Comment: Do you really need a `CURSOR` here? SQL is a set based language, and a `CURSOR` is the opposite of that. You also have a a recursive multi-line scalar function here, which is going to also be a pretty poor performer.

Comment: @Larnu yes i need to follow this approach.. Please suggest if there is any other Alternative of if you have implemented the same condition using another approach,i would like to know :)

Comment: @Larnu  I believe This approach will work,As i am getting wrong output.. This code needs a small correction, which i am seeking for. would be really grateful if you  suggest me something if you find something wrong here.

Comment: it looks to me that you have thougt this in C# and translated it into sql with cursor and recursive function with auto update table while in hold with cursor lock ! I'm not surprised that it is not giving you results. the hole concept might be ok in C# but so wrong in SQL. Think of a hole SET not just line by line. why not try the ranking function RANK() with   integer divide by 26 for the first letter and modulo 26 for second letter [Letter1] = CHAR(ASCII('A')+(RANK()over(order by dt)-1)/26), [Letter2] = CHAR(ASCII('A')+(RANK()over(order by dt)-1)%26)